# What about terraform versioning scheme?

Tags: terraform, versioning

I've been using *terraform* for some time now and a doubt always come to my mind is, which *versioning scheme* is terraform-core using?

Is it *semantic versioning* AKA semver? Because if it is, why an upgrade in the minor version, as when upgrading a project from 0.11.X to 0.12.Y writes the state of terraform with that 0.12.x and it is not allowed to downgrade it back to 0.11.x?

Another thing related : why they opt for starting their version numbers in *0.X.X* rather that 1.X.X? Does it mean anything?

Comment: In semver and pre 1.0, breaking changes are allowed in what would be the minor version. So with Terraform core you can expect breaking changes between 0.11 and 0.12.

Comment: https://semver.org/ explains that pre 1.0 the API cannot be considered stable and that breaking changes are allowed in any version change. In practice, breaking changes tend to increment the minor version, not the patch version, even if they don't add any new functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do use semantic versioning, but their interpretation is a little different than most.

Here's an answer on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15839) from a Hashicorp employee regarding their versioning methodology:

> At HashiCorp we take the idea of a v1.0 very seriously, and once Terraform gets there it will represent a strong promise of compatibility because we believe that the configuration language, internal architecture, CLI, and other product features are right for the long haul.
>
> The current state of Terraform is a little more subtle. We do still consider backward-compatibility very important since we know there is a lot of production infrastructure depending on Terraform today. We must therefore make compromises so we can keep making progress towards something we could make v1.0 promises about. While we keep these disruptions to a minimum, they cannot always be avoided, and so we try to be very explicit about them in the changelog and, where applicable, in upgrade guides.
>
> With this in mind, at this time we suggest always referring to the changelog before upgrading since this is our primary means to note any special considerations that apply during an upgrade. We try to reserve significant breaking changes for increases to the second (traditionally "minor") position in the version number, which at this time represent our "major" development milestones as we work towards an eventual v1.0.
>
> Since Terraform is an application rather than a library we do not intend to follow the Semantic Versioning conventions to the letter, but since they do indeed represent common versioning idiom we are likely to follow them in spirit, since of course we wish to be as clear as possible. As @kshep noted, v0 releases are special in the semver conventions, but the meaning of v1.0 in semver is broadly consistent with how we intend to interpret it.
>
> I'm sorry that our version numbering practices caused confusion here; based on this feedback, we will attempt to be clearer about the significance and risk of each release when we announce it and will work on writing some more explicit documentation on what I wrote above.

Ref: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15839#issuecomment-323106524

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-hashicorp-terraform-1-0-general-availability

From here on you can expect regular semantic versioning support.

Comment: Good one @Mike!